# How can I create a dict of dicts in recursion with a provided list of keys

Tags: python, logic

For example:

I need to create a dict of dicts when iterating over a list of keys

For example, I have this list

```py
my_dict = {'root': {}}
my_keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum']
```

I wanna create a function to return this following dict

```py
my_dict = {
    'root': {
        'foo': {
            'bar': {
                'lorem': {
                    'ipsum': {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think something using recursion, but I'm stucked in the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function:

```
curr_d = my_dict['root']
for k in my_keys:
    curr_d = curr_d.setdefault(k, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
cur_level = my_dict["root"]
for key in my_keys:
    cur_level[key] = {}
    cur_level = cur_level[key]
```